# Is it possible to write Haskell's flip function in Rust?

Tags: haskell, rust

Haskell's [flip](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) function is defined as follows:

```hs
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip f x y =  f y x
```

All it does is take a function and return another function that has its two parameters reversed. If you called a function `f` as `f a b` (`f(a, b)` in Rust-like syntax), you would call `flip f` as `(flip f) b a`.

My unsuccessful attempt at writing this in Rust:

```rust
fn flip<A, B, C, F: Fn(A, B) -> C>(f: F) -> impl Fn(B, A) -> C {
    |a, b| f(b, a)
}
```

Is it possible to write this in Rust?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what error you're getting, but I was able to implement it properly with this code ([playground link for testing](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2b7f5d2e4627fca0dc7291247e546198)):

```
fn flip<A, B, C, F>(f: F) -> impl Fn(B, A) -> C where F: Fn(A, B) ->C {
    move |a,b| f(b, a)
}

fn main() {
    let sub = |a, b| a - b;
    let flipped = flip(sub);
    println!("Result: {}", flipped(5, 10));
}
```

Note the `move` keyword here, which is required to force the closure returned by `flip` to take ownership of `f`.

Comment: Oh, I was just missing the `move`. Thanks!